# Dynamically linking against Hunspell in Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have a project in which I would like to dynamically link to the Hunspell library so my app can have spell-check. The only problem is, I have no idea how to do it. I'm more familiar with the concept in Visual Studio/ C# but I've never done it in a Qt/C++ app before. I did some research and I learned how to put a reference to the library in my project file but I still haven't figured out how to #include it in the classes that need it (the library never shows up in that list Qt Creator offers for header includes). Hopefully it's the correct library; It's the libhunspell-1.3.so.0 file  from Ubuntu's "libhunspell-1.3-0" package.

I intend to release on Linux and Windows (and maybe Mac at some point, if I ever find a way to maintain the app on that platform). I know most Linux distros have ready-made Hunspell libraries in their repositories. I hope I can use those to prevent any potential distribution/licensing pitfalls. On Windows I'll probably have to roll my own DLL from source but hopefully the process of linking against it will be the same.

This part of Qt programming is completely new to me so I would really appreciate any info/help you guys can give me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to get include headers for that lib, then you just may either include them into your project or append `INCLUDEPATH` qmake variable with a path to that headers.

Comment: I got it working, thanks for your help! It turns out I had to use the libhunspell-dev package instead because that one has both the libraries and headers in it (instead of just the libraries). I added references for those to my project file, recompiled, and it worked.